# Determining type of Wifi connection

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

How do you determine which type of Wifi connection a computer is currently using?

For example, is the computer connected using an 802.11b, 802.11g, 802.11n, or 802.11ac connection?

Since, for example 802.11n Wifi adapters can connect with 802.11g or 802.11b, I want to know which method is actually used for the connection.

Answers should be compatible with Windows 7 SP1.

Comment: @slhck Can you answer this question since you are sure there's information available?

Comment: Does that help? http://superuser.com/questions/403320/get-the-wireless-adapter-frequency-band-mode-in-windows-7

Comment: @slhck I don't think so.  I think the 'radio type' field in netsh specified the type of radio and not how the radio is currently connected.  But I could be mistaken.

Comment: Maybe you can try it and come back with the results. I don't use Windows so I can't check.

Comment: @slhck I tried it out before posting.  There is no way to tell, hence this question.

Comment: Couldn't you disable specific connection types on your router and  then see what the command outputs? Of course it depends on how configurable the router is.

Comment: @slhck No. I don't think corporate will go for that.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows click on the wifi icon in the bottom right of your screen. Mouse over that WiFi you are connected to, and it will tell you.

Comment: I double checked and this worked for me in Windows 7 Pro SP1.   It should say your connection next to Radio Type.
If it doesn't work for you, instead of mousing over to the network, right click on it, click status and check out what it says for Speed.  You can determine your connection based on what it says.