# how to see what frequency the wireless network is using

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

Say I'm connected to a particular access point and that I'm using Windows 10 Pro. How would I be able to find out if the access point is using 2.4GHz or 5GHz?

Comment: You can access the AP and check your connection status depending on your AP's firmware, or you can install a software like this one: https://www.acrylicwifi.com/en/wlan-software/wlan-scanner-acrylic-wifi-free/ which can give you the needed info

Comment: Dupe: [Get the wireless adapter frequency-band mode in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/q/403320)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Windows 10 (once you connect) you just go to Settings / Network & Internet / click on the SSID name and scroll down to Properties. 
It tells you the band, protocol, channel, security type, and all that good stuff.

This works only on Windows 10 Anniversary Update (version 1607) and up.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Clicking on the SSID name just displays a "Disconnect" button. There is no "Properties" section or button anywhere to be seen.

Comment: Windows 10? Mine shows it. Just checked again. It even shows a "properties" if I click on the SSID down in the taskbar. I guess I am running the preview version on this PC though...

Comment: Mine is Windows 10 Pro, updated from Windows 7 Professional. German locale, but I'm sure I'd recognize any of the translations for "properties" Microsoft would come up with. (Although their German translations are often quite strange and inconsistent.)

Comment: I also don't have the SSID anywhere in the taskbar, just the WLAN icon which displays the SSID as mouseover. If I click on that I get the list of visible WLANs, with mine marked as "connected, secured", and if I click on that, the "disconnect" button appears, nothing else. At the bottom of the list is a link "network settings" and two buttons to switch off the WLAN or to switch to airplane mode.

Comment: You are correct. I setup and tried this on a PC not running the Preview version and it wasn't there. I will try updating one of these PC's to the "windows 10 anniversary update" and see if it shows up then or if it's just a preview thing. (not sure why the anniversary update doesn't seem to be auto updating yet) I'll update this with what I find out. Thanks

Comment: It is a "windows 10 anniversary update" feature. So it won't be on your PC till it's updated. Either Automatically by windows or manually by you.

Answer (score 14):

on windows commandline: `netsh wlan show interfaces`

See Radio Type and Channel

Comment: Upvoted. This worked for me on Win7. I had to look up the channel # in a table to see the GHz. Roundabout, but it worked.

Comment: yeah, for this purpose you need to look at Channel, but that is pretty darn indicative...  in the US the 2GHz channels are 1-11 ...  bigger numbers are 5GHz

Answer (score 3):

For **Windows 11**:

1. Open **Settings**
2. Go to **Network & internet**
3. Tap **Properties**
   [image: Network & internet, WiFi properties, on Windows 11]
4. Scroll down and you will see the network band and channel
   [image: Network band and channel in Settings on Windows 11]

---

It doesn't show the width or how many channels you're using right now, only the control channel. In my case I'm actually using channels 36 through 64 (160 MHz). For more detailed info I'd recommend [Acrylic Wi-Fi Home](https://www.acrylicwifi.com/en/downloads-free-license-wifi-wireless-network-software-tools/download-wifi-scanner-windows/).

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 Home:

Network settings> wifi> advanced options

or

System information> Components> Network> Adapter> scroll down to wireless section