# How to see Wi-Fi channel width in Windows?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

I've looked everywhere and even tried the famous software inSSIDer but it doesn't work with 160 MHz networks. I can't find out if I'm actually using 160 MHz after getting a router capable of that. I've been searching for months. Is there any way to see that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a software suggestion in [a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1066984/how-to-see-what-frequency-the-wireless-network-is-using/1671504#comment1502149_1066984) on a related question. The software [Acrylic Wi-Fi Home](https://www.acrylicwifi.com/en/wlan-wifi-wireless-network-software-tools/wlan-scanner-acrylic-wifi-free/), which is a free-for-personal-use application, is 802.11ax compatible and can show 160 MHz networks as well as 4x4.

In the below screenshot you can clearly see that the router has 160 MHz 4x4 enabled.

[image: 160 MHz network in Acrylic Wi-Fi Home]